# Why is the UEFI admin password is asking this password at each reboot?

Tags: boot, bios, installation, passwords

I am currently setting a new home server; a Qotom Mini PC. It is equipped with an AMI BIOS/UEFI v2.19 UEFI 2.6.

I've set a BIOS/UEFI password "administrator" only (no "user" password).

I expected the computer to behave like [indicated here](https://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile4/1-1VLXEHN/The%20Administrator%20and%20User%20password%20mechanism%20for%20AMI%20BIOS.pdf), i.e that the BIOS/UEFI password will be asked only when trying to enter the BIOS/UEFI set-up menu. **But instead, it is asking this password at each reboot!**

As I'm trying to set up a headless server, this behaviour is not acceptable.

I've tried other combinations: user only password, admin only password and user and admin passwords. In each case, I'm asked for password at boot. The only configuration where no password is asked at boot, is with no BIOS/UEFI password set.

1. How do I get the intended behaviour, ie only asked password when trying to modify BIOS/UEFI?
2. Is there a relation with the secureboot status?

---

**Edit**: With current BIOS, I made some various tests with different status for secure boot, but password keeps being asked at each reboot.

Comment: Which model is the computer and is the BIOS fully updated? Please add a screenshot of your BIOS/UEFI screen where the passwords are specified. Note that the BIOS-only password is normally called "Supervisor", not "Administrator".

Comment: Model is Q20321G9 similar to [this one](https://qotom.net/product/RouterPC_Q20331G9S10.html#product-content3) but with C3558R processor. Screenshot is similar to the [Advantech PDF](https://advdownload.advantech.com/productfile/Downloadfile4/1-1VLXEHN/The%20Administrator%20and%20User%20password%20mechanism%20for%20AMI%20BIOS.pdf) I refered to, except that there is an additional "secure boot" line. Password are called "Administrator" and "User" exactly like in the PDF screenshot.

Comment: Right, and it's non-standard terminology. I searched a bit and summarized my findings in an answer (too long for a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After engaging with Qotom support, they issued a new version of the BIOS/UEFI.

The new one (dated Feb 2024) behaves correctly regarding the admin password: It is only asked when trying to enter set-up.

Bugs can indeed be everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

I found
[this list](http://www.qotom.us/download/Bios/Q20300G9_QDNV01/Q20300G9_Readme.txt)
of BIOS versions where there are two QDNV0111.V10 BIOS for
Q20321G9 with C3558R dating from 2023-8-29.

Once you decide which one sounds like yours, you may download from
[here](http://www.qotom.us/download/Bios/Q20300G9_QDNV01/).
Miraculously, the packages were updated in 2024, so the dates
in the list are incorrect.

The documentation is not great, so be very careful.
Take backups of your data and stop for the least warning sign, as
a bad BIOS can make the computer unusable.
Getting in touch with Qotom Support might be a good idea
(if they answer).

Comment: thanks for the help. QDNV0111.V10 from 2023-8-29 is the bios currently installed. In the newer .zip the file called QDNV0111.V10 is dating from dec 2023, so I'll try to update with it.

Comment: Not possible to update with [the given procedure](https://qotom.net/faq/31.html): 1. in bios mode, Freedos states "bad command" (it certainsly expects .exe and not .efi nor .nsh) 2. in UEFI mode, "error 252 image file not found" (and when I type ls, Shell states "No mapping")

Comment: The `.nsh` file is a batch file, so you could just rename it to `.bat`. However, the question is whether you currently have a BIOS or UEFI computer. If you have Windows, you could run `MSInfo32` and see whet it says about "BIOS Mode".

Comment: The computer is UEFI. Qotom sent me an updated procedure. The missing step was to select the drive in the UEFI shell buy using Fs3: . Refreshing QDNV0111 went well but did nothing to the password issue. When trying QDNV0112, an error occured. The device is not bricked as it is booting into windows but I don't have access to bios anymore. The VGA screen is all black before windows 10. Bios menu may still exist as bot stalls when I press ESC or F1 but screen is all black

Comment: Error was "PDR Region does not exist. Error 25: The host CPU does not have write access to the target flash area.  To enable write access for this operation you must modify the descriptor settings to give host access to this region." I then rebooted. Not sure if it is this error or the change of version that is causing bios black screen. `msinfo32` only shows QDNV01 so, i'm not sure on witch version I'm on...

Comment: The BIOS seems to be locked. Qotom Support might be able to help, but be careful. I suggest to verify again with them that this is the correct BIOS version.